# Object entries returning undefined

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a json object returned from a SQL query. I want to filter out the json key before sending back to the front end. If the key is true, return back to the front end is what I am looking for.

In my server file I have this line.

```
          let returned_data = Object.entries(queried_data[0]).forEach((key, value) => {
            return value === true ? key : null
          })
          res.json(returned_data)
```

This is an example of my returned json after SQL querying.

```
[{first_name: 'testing', has_apple: true, has_pear: true, has_beans: false}]
```

I am expecting the `returned_data` to have `['has_apple', 'has_pear']`. Right now I am getting undefined for `returned_data`

Comment: `Object.entries()` never returns `undefined`. `forEach` always does.

Comment: Are you positive you aren't required to perform a JSON operation on `queried_data` prior to interacting with it with `Object`?

Comment: @theaccordance You are right, I can see something is not right from the console.log, after changing from `forEach` to `map` I am getting a messed up output. I need to see which JSON operation I will need to do.

Comment: Try JSON.parse()

Comment: I got it working already. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything `map` does. Also `Object.entries` returns an array of arrays and hence you need to destructure the value in map function to get key and value. Change your code to

```
      let returned_data = Object.entries(queried_data[0]).map(([key, value]) => {
        return value === true ? key : null
      })
      res.json(returned_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am getting something in the return.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers say forEach() doesn’t return anything so either you have to use map() or create an array and push value to it if true

```
var new_data=[];
Object.entries(queried_data[0]).forEach((key, value) => {
       if( value===true){new_data.push(key)}
});
console.log(new_data);
```

Comment: This gives exactly what I wanted for the result. I will try out others' solutions too for knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
const returned_data = Object.entries(queried_data[0]).map((key, value) => {
    return value === true ? key : null
}).filter(key => {
    return key !== null
});
```

or simply

```
const returned_data = Object.keys(queried_data[0]).filter(key, queried_data[0][key] === true);
```

Don't use `forEach`!